# Strings container size, calculating minimum width given maximum height

Tags: objective-c, string, cocoa, swift

Most needs for fitting a formatted string require calculating a the **height** of a container given a  maximum width to for the string into.  Such functions in cocoa API reflect this e.g.

```
NSTextField.sizeThatFits()
```

This method will take the maximum width as fixed and adjust the height to contain the text.

How would you do the opposite with the above - given a height limit, calculate the smallest **width** to enclose the text?

One way I've first thought of is by first creating an estimate by dividing the area of a single line of text by the required height to get an estimated width. But this will always be an overestimation of the height, because words will wrap, pushing other words along and down. The next stage of the algorithm, takes this excess height and adds it onto the end of the imaginary rectangle, until the maximum height limit is broken, giving an upper and lower estimate of the width. The final part of the algorithm converges with a kind of binary search until a certain pixel tolerance is reached.  I will post this as an answer when I can.

I feel there must be a better way of doing this? (ObjC or Swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Calculating text width given maximum height:**

Here is the code that works well for me on average it calculates 3 or 4 sizes when the tolerance is set to 5.  You can replace with whatever size calculating function you like, e.g. your function above. Set the tolerance based on how tight you want it.  Hope this helps - it can definitely be optimised (if you sacrifice readability a bit more)

```
func setLabelSize {

    var max_height = CGFloat(200) //This is the maximum height
    var big_float = CGFloat(99999)
    var width_estimate = big_float //This is the initial estimate

    var old_size = label.sizeThatFits(NSSize(width: width_estimate, height: big_float))

    width_estimate = old_size.width * old_size.height / max_height

    var new_size = label.sizeThatFits(NSSize(width: width_estimate, height: big_float))
    var old_width_estimate = width_estimate

    //first estimate will always be short, so loop until upper bound is found
    while (new_size.height < max_height) {
        old_width_estimate = width_estimate
        old_size = new_size

        var surpless_area = (new_size.height - max_height) * width_estimate
        width_estimate += (surpless_area / new_size.height) 

        new_size = label.sizeThatFits(NSSize(width: width_estimate, height: big_float))
        println("estimate: \(width_estimate) old_estimate: \(old_width_estimate) new_size: \(new_size) old_size: \(old_size)")
    }

    //value is inbetween old_width_estimate and width_estimate
    //width_estimate should be lower estimate, old should be higher
    var upper_estimate = old_width_estimate
    var lower_estimate = width_estimate
    var upper_estimate_size = old_size
    var tolerance = CGFloat(5)

    while(true) {

        var diff = (upper_estimate - lower_estimate) / 2
        println("upper: \(upper_estimate) lower: \(lower_estimate) diff: \(diff)")
        if diff <= tolerance {
            break
        } else {
            var half_estimate = lower_estimate + diff
            new_size = label.sizeThatFits(NSSize(width: half_estimate, height: big_float))
            if new_size.height>max_height {
                lower_estimate = half_estimate
            } else {
                upper_estimate = half_estimate
                upper_estimate_size = new_size
            }
        }
    }

    println("Final size \(upper_estimate_size)")

    label.frame.size = upper_estimate_size
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about getting the height and width of the attributed string and then finding how many times the height of the string fits into your height limit and then dividing the width of the string by that as follows:

```
NSAttributedString *myString = /*an attributed string*/
NSSize rawSize = myString.size; /*imagine a size of h20w100*/
int heightLimit = 40; /*example height limit*/
int linesAvailable = heightLimit/rawSize.height; /*gets the max number of lines available for the text*/
int neededWidth = rawSize.width/linesAvailable; /*gets the width of field needed to fit the whole text in the available height*/
NSSize fieldSize = NSMakeSize(needeWidth,heightLimit);
```

This should provide you with a text field with the correct width to fit the string in with a limited height (in this case you would have 2 lines available and thus need a width of 50).

Comment: This is a start, but will be in accurate due to word wrapping making some lines necessarily longer, also I checked and the height of a single length of string does not accurately divide into the heightlimit, as multiple lines have greater height due to spacing inbetween.  Thanks for the answer though!